# How would I reference MDbootstrap stylesheet in html

Tags: html, mdbootstrap

I am aware that in HTML the way to reference stylesheets is something along these lines:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

But what is the stylesheet reference for MDboostrap. I have looked all over the website and I can't find it and the website says that all the resources are free. Have I got to install something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick research and I could find that you can download `MDBoostrap` or use the CDN. Links bellow:

- Download page: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/getting-started/download/
- CDN examples: https://mdbootstrap.com/md-bootstrap-cdn/

Comment: It helped thank you very much. You also helped me to learn something new today: What CDN stands for (content delivery network). Thank you! :)